# Qt C++ QGridLayout - компоновка виджетов в зависимости от размеров окна

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

Мне необходимо размещать виджеты на QGridLayout в зависимости от размеров окна.

Допутим, у нас на QGridLayout есть несколько три одинаковых элемента, которые размещены горизонтально, то есть их общая ширина, например будет totalWidth / 3, которая больше текущего размера окна. В этом случае последний виджет необходимо переместить на следующую строку:
Было:
widget widget widget
Стало:
widget widget
widget

Есл же снова уменьшить ширину окна, места остаётся ещё меньше и нужно сделать так, чтобы все виджеты были в отдельных строках:
widget
widget
widget

Я создал класс `Widget`, который наследуется от `QWidget` и создал в нём QGridLayout и создал метод `addWidget(QWidget *w)`, который каждый раз добавляет виджет по горизонтали в конец.

> Помогите, пожалуйта, написать функцию, которая бы после добавления виджета в конец, компоновала бы их так, чтобы они отображались таким образом, как я описал выше. Эту функцию я буду вызывать в `resizeEvent` и непосредственно в функции 
>   Widget::addWidget()

Comment: Вам надо делать свой собственный лэйаут. Под ваши запросы подходит вот этот пример https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html